# auto_increment property not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, auto-increment

I have initialized a database `users` like this `create table users (id not null auto_increment primary key, first_name varchar(256) not null, last_name varchar(256) not null);`
However, I can just execute `insert into users values (2,'James','Bond');` and no error is thrown. I want to create a table so that the primary key gets auto incremented and one can simply add entries like so: `insert into users values ("firstname","lastname");` is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

The fact a column is auto-incrementing doesn't mean you can just ignore it in an insert statement. You could, however, avoid assigning a value to it and letting the auto_increment property handle it by using the `default` keyword:

```sql
insert into users values (default, 'firstname', 'lastname');
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the syntax `insert into users values ('firstname','lastname');` i.e. you do not specify a list of columns, this  implies your VALUES clause will contain values for all columns. This is not related to using auto_increment, it applies to any table.

You can work around this by specifying the columns:

```
insert into users (firstname, lastname) values ('firstname','lastname');
```

By omitting `id` from the list of columns, it should also be omitted from the VALUES clause.

Another form of INSERT syntax supported by MySQL (although it's nonstandard) might be more clear. It also allows you to omit columns you don't want to set in your INSERT statement.

```
insert into users SET firstname='firstname', lastname='lastname;
```

If you do include the `id` column either implicitly or explicitly, you can trigger the auto-increment behavior by using `NULL`, `DEFAULT`, or if the sql mode permits it, `0`.

If you specify any other value for the `id`, it overrides the auto-increment.

This is all documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html and related pages linked by that page.

Answer (score 1):

you can name the columns that you want to insert.

But if you have more t columns , you have to define DEFAULT values, so that Mysql knows how to fill the not inserted values

```
INSERT INTO users (first_name ,last_name ) VALUEs("firstname","lastname");
```